# Why is (tri-)ammonium phosphate ((NH4)3PO4) so unstable?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, pnictogen

Why is triammonium phosphate, $\ce{(NH4)3PO4}$, so much more unstable than diammonium phosphate, $\ce{(NH4)2HPO4}$, or monoammonium phosphate, $\ce{NH4H2PO4})$?

Answer (score 1):

> Ammonium phosphates are solids between 0 and 75°C. **Because ammonium
>   hydroxide $(\ce{NH4OH})$ is a much weaker base than the common metal
>   hydroxides, ammonium phosphates are comparatively unstable.**  Both
>   triammonium phosphate ($\ce{(NH4)3PO4}$) and the double salt
>   ($\ce{(NH4)3PO4.2(NH4)2HPO4}$) are unstable at room temperature and
>   evolve ammonia to form diammonium phosphate. Even the commercial mono-
>   and diammonium phosphates exhibit an ammonium vapor pressure in the
>   solid form and in solution. Although MAP is more stable than DAP, it
>   decomposes at high temperature to give ammonia and polyphosphoric
>   acid. Diammonium phosphate decomposes to give ammonia and monoammonium
>   phosphate at around 70°C.

**Source:** (2005) Ammonium Phosphates and Ammonium Sulfate. In: Synthetic Nitrogen Products. Springer, Boston, MA. [DOI: 10.1007/0-306-48639-3_12](https://doi.org/10.1007/0-306-48639-3_12).

Comment: I honestly don't understand why $\ce{NH4OH}$ being a weaker base makes TAP and DAP be unstable.

Comment: Looking at vapor pressures of NH3 for those solids would be a good idea...